# Animate header with jquery on user scroll

Tags: jquery, html

i have the next code wich allow me to add and remove a class when user reach certain point of page scroll, and them, i want to animate the header

```
 $(document).scroll(function (e) {
var value = $(this).scrollTop();
if (value > 150) {
    $( "body" ).addClass( "scroll" );
    $( "header.head" ).stop().animate({top:'-30px'}); 
 }
else {
    $( "body" ).removeClass( "scroll" );
    $("header.head" ).stop().animate({top:'0px'});
 }
```

my problem is that the initial animation (top: -30px) works perfect, but them, when i scroll up, the top: 0px doesnt work.
and also, when i scroll up and then go back, the top:-30px doesnt repeat

you can see it at here [sample]http://www.pabloscillia.com.ar/clientes/yumyum/[1](http://www.pabloscillia.com.ar/clientes/yumyum/)

my intention is that, at >150 execute a animation, and then, when user is <150 execute another (also dont know why animation sometimes is longer and sometimes shorter)

i really dont know where to look in order to make it work
thanks a lot in advance

Comment: yes, i just add the url

Comment: It's working for me on Chrome.

Comment: If you use HTML5 why boring about animate by js ?

Comment: your code not works, because you add `$( "body" ).removeClass( "scroll" );` before animation, add it as function at second argument of animate, and use finish() not stop() here (in true case of condition).

Answer (score 0):

Replace code with the following:

```
var $head = $("header.head"),
    $body = $("body"),current=0;

$(document).scroll(function (e) {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (value > 150) {
        if (current==1) return;
        current=1;
        $head.stop();
        $body.addClass("scroll");
        $head.css({top: -150});
        $head.animate({
            top: '-30'
        },"fast");
    } else {
        if (current==2) return;
        current=2;
        $head.stop().animate({
            top: '-150'
        }, "fast",endScrollClass);
    }
});

function endScrollClass() {
    $body.removeClass("scroll");
    $head.css('top',0)
}
```

this will run endScrollClass on end of animate(), not run animation every time, etc, I made [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/sdFVs/);

Comment: this makes the end animation, but is not executing the start animation

Comment: ok, I checked, stop() should work for you, also I think you should flag state of the header, to not do anymation on every scroll

Comment: to get good effect, I think you should 1st - calculate position of the header before changing class, set class, and place header to "old" place (when changing from absolute to fixed)

Comment: found several other pitfalls here, I hope you wanted this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Give header two classes, default and fixed, add default class to header `<header class="default">` and write up class `.fixed {...}` in CSS for header styling when it's fixed. Here's a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/EGmeV/)**

```
<header class="default"></header>


header {
  background: #555;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}
.default {
  /* Add some properties to defaut if you wish */
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


$(function() {

  var header = $('header');
  var headOff = header.offset();

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(this).scrollTop() > 150 + headOff.top && header.hasClass('default')) {
      header.fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('default').addClass('fixed').fadeIn('fast').animate({ height: '70px'}, 350);
      });
    } 
    else if($(this).scrollTop() <= 150 + headOff.top && header.hasClass('fixed')) {
      header.fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default').fadeIn('fast').animate({ height: '120px'}, 350);
      });
    }
  });

});
```